# this.errors.clear(); Not working on Ajax request

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios

Am trying submit a form using axios and vuejs. I want to clear all error after form is successfully submitted. I know `this.errors.clear();` will not work because am in the axios object so I decided to hook onto my vue instance which is the `contact` variable and do `contact.errors.clear();` But it still does not work.

This is my js.

```
   new Vue({
      el: '#contact',

      data: {

      token: '',
      name: '',
      email: '',
      message: ''
  },

   methods: {

     axiosHeaders() {
         axios.create({
          timeout: 1000,
          headers: {'X-Custom-Header': token}
        });
    },

     onSubmitContactForm() {
        $this = this;
        this.axiosHeaders();
         axios({

         method: 'post',

          url: contactForm,

         data: {
            token: this.token,
            name: this.name,
            email: this.email,
            message: this.message
         }

      }).then((response) => {

          $vm.errors.clear();
          $this.successMessage();
          $this.name = ''; $this.email = ''; $this.message = '';

       }).catch((error) => {

        $this.errorMessage();
        console.log(error.response);
    });


    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you try `$vm.contact.errors.clear();`

Comment: My ajax request is now jumping to the catch promise. And returning an error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined   at axios.then.catch (contact:398)
    at <anonymous>`

Comment: maybe error does.response.data does not exist

Comment: But the code does not jump to that part if i take `$vm.contact.errors.clear();` off

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. The way you are using the error handler is very wrong. I suggest you use errorHandler and not to use `$vm.`... you are creating unnecessary complexity

Comment: I don't get what you mean...

Comment: it means, you don't need to do `let contact = new Vue({})` just use `new Vue({})` maybe it's just me but I never used it like that and I can access everything I need in vue with `this`

Comment: Ok I have edited my code above. Kindly have a look at it again and see if you can help me

Comment: can you post it in jsfiddle? if not I it might take me a bit more to help

Comment: Place this `$this.$validator.clean();` just after `$this.name = ''; $this.email = ''; $this.message = '';`